# Combine JS and CSS to one file

Tags: javascript, css, gruntjs

I have a sample.min.js and sample.min.css files. I just want one file sample.min.js that has all JS and CSS content. I am using grunt, and I am not sure whether there is a plugin to do that.

Any help or advice will be great.

Comment: bad idea, those are 2 different languages and are called separately. One via `<link>` and the other via `<script>`. If you want to reduce http requests you can put your css directly onto the page in the `<style>` block

Comment: Why would you do this? Two files is already pretty good.

Comment: Lol, maybe have the css as a string in your js file, then dynamically create a <style> element?

Comment: @DmitryNarkevich interesting idea. I'd still say it's bad practice though.

Comment: You could have css and js combined together in your development files, and use grunt to compile them into separate .css and .js files the browser can read -- vue components do this for example -- but you can't reasonably do it the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against that. While you could possibly convert your CSS into a javascript equivalent, it would be much slower than native CSS.

Just be alright with the fact that you will have to have 2 files, but as long as you combine all of your CSS into one file and all of your JS into another file, you are still doing the right thing when it comes to load optimization.

Also, combining these 2 files into one can actually **hurt** performance. That is because the browser can download more than one file at a time simultaneously. If you combine them into one file, however, there is no chance that the browser can take advantage of that.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an HTML file and put all your JS in a `<script>` tag and all your CSS in a `<style>` tag. But this would be a phenomenally silly idea and would make readability damn near impossible.